# Can someone explain why $x''+xx'=0$ is non linear equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Why differential equation as this $x''+xx'=0$ is non linear?

Comment: $$xx' = \left( \frac{x^{2}}{2} \right)'$$

Comment: Knowing "something like" what a linear equation is is better than nothing, but it's not that hard to know _exactly_ what a second-order linear DE is: A DE of the form $x''+a(t)x'+b(t)x=g(t)$.. Period.

Comment: The collections "linear differential equations" and "non-linear differential equations" are exhaustive and mutually exclusive.  Every differential equation falls into one (and only one) of those collections.  Typically, linear DEs are defined in a precise manner (e.g. as @DavidC.Ullrich has done above), and everything else is non-linear.  So, in order to answer your question:  first, ask yourself if the equation is linear.  If not, it must be non-linear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of doubt you can always check if it's linear. Let $f(x)=x''+xx'$. If $f$ is linear then it should satisfy $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ as well as $f(ax)=af(x)$ but one can see that

$$\begin{align}f(x+y)&=(x+y)''+(x+y)(x+y)'\\ &=x''+y''+(x+y)(x'+y') \\ &=x''+xx'+y''+yy'+xy'+yx' \\ 
&=f(x)+f(y)+xy'+yx' \\
&\neq f(x)+f(y)
\end{align}$$

hence it is not linear.

Comment: Its slightly easier to check the other condition, since $ 2xx' \neq (2x)(2x)' = 4xx'$

Comment: That is also an option, I had already started checking the first condition so I didn't bother checking the next.

Answer (score 2):

Because if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two solutions then $x_3=x_1+x_2$ must be another solution (notice that equation is homogeneous). We have $x_1''+x_1 x_1'=0$ and $x_2''+x_2 x_2'=0$ but 
\begin{align}
x_3''+x_3 x_3'
&=(x_1+x_2)''+(x_1+x_2)'(x_1+x_2) \\
&=\left(x_1''+(x_1 x_1')\right)+\left(x_2''+(x_2 x_2')\right) + x_1'x_2+x_2'x_1=0 +0 + x_1'x_2+x_2'x_1,
\end{align}
which is not necessary zero and hence the equation is not linear.